# Mock inherited protected method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I here have a simplified version of my problem. Class A has a protected method. Class B inherits this method.

```
public class A{
    protected String getString(){
        //some Code
    }
}


public class B extends A{
    public void doSomething(){
        //someCode
        String result = getString();
    }
}
```

I now write a Unit-Test with Mockito, which is in another package-test and I want to test the `doSomething()` method. To do that, I need to mock the getString()-call. Since the method is protected and my test-class is in a differnet package, I can't use `doReturn(...).when(classUnderTest).getString()`. The thing is, that I spy on class B. So I can't use `mock(new B(), Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)`.

I tried getting the protected method via Reflection:

```
Method getString = classUnderTest.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getString");
getString.setAccessible(true);
```

But I then don't know how to use this inside `doReturn()`.

Comment: Why are you trying to test something that's not in the same package as where you're testing it?  That may be the first thing you want to correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 'override and subclass'

```
B b = new B() {
  @Override
  protected String getString() {
    return "FAKE VALUE FOR TESTING PURPOSES";
  };
};
```

Comment: I was able to mock protected method only using Mockito and Java Reflection. Added answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69214170/2367394

Answer (score 2):

There might be a cleaner way of doing this, but here goes...

1. Create a mock for "A"
2. Create another class that extends B and overrides the method
3. Make the overridden method call the mock

For example...

```
private A partialMock;
private B classUnderTest;

@Before
public void setup() {
    partialMock = mock(A.class);
    classUnderTest = new B() {
        @Override
        protected String getString() {
            return partialMock.getString();
        }
    };
}

@Test
public void shouldDoSomething() {

    when(partialMock.toString()).thenReturn("[THE MOCKED RESPONSE]");

    classUnderTest.doSomething();

    // ...verify stuff...
}
```

Obviously you don't even need to use mocking, you can just return something directly from the overridden method.

Comment: I was able to mock protected method only using Mockito and Java Reflection. Added answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69214170/2367394

Answer (score 0):

Something like following worked for me, using [doReturn()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.12.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12) and Junit5's [ReflectionSupport](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.commons/org/junit/platform/commons/support/ReflectionSupport.html).

[Note: I tested on Mockito 3.12.4]

```java
var a = spy(new A);
ReflectionSupport.invokeMethod(
        a.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("getString"),
        doReturn("FAKE VALUE FOR TESTING PURPOSES").when(a));
```

Comment: I think you mean `new B()` rather than `new A` to meet the problem as described.
I suspect this only works in the case where A and B are in the same package.
For the problem I have A and B are in different packages and this approach doesn't work (as it stands)